# Not understanding output of MonthEnd() in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Say i have the following:

```
start = dt.datetime(2015,07,01)
end = dt.datetime(2016,06,30)

rng = pd.date_range(start, end,freq='M')

print rng

DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-31', '2015-08-31', '2015-09-30', '2015-10-31',
           '2015-11-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-01-31', '2016-02-29',
           '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

I would expect :

```
rng[0] + MonthBegin()
```

to give an output of '2015-07-01'. instead it shows '2015-08-01'

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Anchored Offset Semantics](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics) section of the documentation.

Anchored offsets will snap to the *next* anchor point. If your date is within a month, `MonthBegin()` will snap to the beginning of the next month.

If you want the beginning of the current month, you can either subtract `MonthBegin()`:

```
rng[0] - MonthBegin()
```

Or you can add `MonthBegin(-1)`:

```
rng[0] + MonthBegin(-1)
```